# Selecting in Bigquery doesn't retrieve all data more than 53000 rows

Tags: google-bigquery

The table named student_master in bigquery has 70000 rows and I would like to retrieve rows using this query. I found no error when doing this, however, it just retrieve 52226 rows (means, not all). I try to use row_number() over partition_by like this code but still didn't get all data. What should I do?

I am using the idea of using two query `order by id_student`, `limit 35000`, and make `asc` (query1), `desc`(query2) but it will not works if the data increase (let's say 200000 rows).

```
data= []
sql = ( "SELECT id_student, class,name," +
        "   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY class ASC) row_num," +
        "FROM" +
        "   [project_name.dataset.student_master]" +
        "WHERE not class = " + element['class']
        )
query = client.run_sync_query(sql)
query.timeout_ms = 20000
query.run()
for row in query.rows:
    data.append(row)
return data
```

Comment: So simple question but as your query has a `WHERE` statement, do you get 70,000 rows if you run it in the BQ UI? And have you tried removing the `query.timeout_ms`?

Comment: No, it is 69900 rows and by removing `query.timeout ` still retrieve same result

Answer (score 1):

In general, for big exports you should run an export job which will place your data into files in GCS.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

But in this case you might just need to go through more pages of results:

> If the rows returned by the query do not fit into the initial response, then we need to fetch the remaining rows via fetch_data():

```
query = client.run_sync_query(LIMITED)
query.timeout_ms = TIMEOUT_MS
query.max_results = PAGE_SIZE
query.run()                     # API request

assert query.complete
assert query.page_token is not None
assert len(query.rows) == PAGE_SIZE
assert [field.name for field in query.schema] == ['name']

iterator = query.fetch_data()   # API request(s) during iteration
for row in iterator:
    do_something_with(row)
```

- https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html

Comment: Are you sure Felipe? I've export more rows than the above (I've got an example sitting in front of me with 98,541 rows) using `query_job = client.query("""SELECT * 
                         FROM project.dataset.table""")

df = query_job.result().to_dataframe()`

Comment: please check the question since it using query to retrieve specific data. thank you, Felipe

Answer (score 1):

I was able to gather 200,000+ rows by querying a public dataset, verified by using a counter variable:

```
query_job = client.query("""
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY token_address ORDER BY token_address ASC) as row_number,token_address
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.token_transfers`
    WHERE token_address = '0x001575786dfa7b9d9d1324ec308785738f80a951'
    ORDER BY 1
    """)
contador = 0
for row in query_job:
    contador += 1
    print(contador,row)
```

Comment: it works if just get id and class fields. but, it doesnt works if get all fields. It's weird. is there any condition which limit the size of data?

Comment: I just did a `SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.token_transfers` WHERE token_address = '0x001575786dfa7b9d9d1324ec308785738f80a951' ORDER BY 1` and got 203435 rows by using the same code. can you please specify your library version? [These are the Query job quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs)

Comment: I suggest try upgrading your client libraries with `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery` to use the latest version, as I'm using version 1.7.0 and got the desired results